# How to visualize a single color (rgb) in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to model a system which creates some color transition effects. I can't find a way to visualize the colors. The closest I've got is to use the "Matrix Viewer" but it just maps the values into a heat map (by default).

How can I visualize a color, by having one huge pixel of that color in simulink?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [Computer Vision System Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/), you can try the [Video Viewer](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/videoviewer.html) block or maybe the [To Video Display](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/tovideodisplay.html) block.

[image: Video Viewer]